# Updating Torrent Trackers Rules

Tags: download, speed, utorrent

If I have a couple of torrents that have the same contents, and I want to update it's trackers, is it necessary for these torrents(*contents*) to Have the exact same names, too?

For example: if these are the torrent's contents:

- Torrent.1:- world.war.z.2013.720.mkv  ----- Size: 946.42 MB
- Torrent.2:- World War Z (2013) Bluray x264 720p.Mkv  ----- Size: 946.42 MB

Is it possible to update the trackers in this example?

And if i did, is it going to make a difference in the downloading speed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not relevant all files have the same  trackers, is something particular to each tracker.

> A [BitTorrent tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker) is a server that assists in the communication
>   between peers using the BitTorrent protocol. In peer-to-peer file
>   sharing a software client on an end-user PC requests a file, and
>   portions of the requested file residing on peer machines are sent to
>   the client, and then reassembled into a full copy of the requested
>   file. The "tracker" server keeps track of where file copies reside on
>   peer machines, which ones are available at time of the client request,
>   and helps coordinate efficient transmission and reassembly of the
>   copied file.